# Changing offline .shp file in sharpmap tutorial code

Tags: c#, shapefile, sharpmap

I am working on a project to integrate a offline map in C#, I want to use sharpmap for offline maps but  I am facing a problem in changing the given shape file(states_ugl) in the tutorial to a different one. I have tried to put many different shape file as  the source in the code but the form appears to blank when it builds up. As I am a fresher to this platform, and  I am just following the tutorial can anyone please suggest any possible solution to this problem.?

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial or project? Can you maybe include your source code?

Comment: Is this the same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262703/issues-loading-different-shapefiles-in-given-sharpmap-tutorial-code Opened just a few hours after this question

Comment: Yes I have the same problem as mention in the link provided by you. Can you please provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving layer style like this

```
layer.Style.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent);
layer.Style.Outline = new Pen(Color.Black);
layer.Style.EnableOutline = true;
layer.MaxVisible = 13000;
```