# Issues loading different shapefiles in given sharpmap tutorial code

Tags: c#, shapefile, sharpmap

I am currently working on sharpmap project with the need to work on offline maps. As i am fresher in this field,I am following the sharpmap tutorial and facing a problem with loading new shape files in the given tutorial code.

For Example :\

```
SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer("States");
    vlay.DataSource = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.ShapeFile("path_to_data\\states_ugl.shp", true);
```

At this line of code, if i pass a different shapefile, code builds with a blank background or no display. 
I have tried with different shape files with different sizes but the result is the same. It only works for the mentioned `states_ugl.shp` file given in the code. Please need help regarding this issue as I am a fresher in this field.
Thanks.

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/201376/115

Answer (score 0):

Try giving layer styling for your layer, something like below.

```
layer.DataSource = DBlayer;
layer.Style.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent);
layer.Style.Outline = new Pen(Color.Black);
layer.Style.EnableOutline = true;
layer.MaxVisible = 13000;
```